# raw/endraw throwing warning on Jekyll 3.3.1

Tags: jekyll

I just upgraded a jekyll-based site to use Jekyll 3.3.1, and it's begun choking on these lines:

```
{% raw %}
<textarea class="codemirror" data-lang="html">
<html>
<head>
  <title>{{$form_name}}</title>
  {{$required_resources}}
</head>
<body></textarea>
{% endraw %}
```

The warning it's throwing is:

```
Liquid Warning: Liquid syntax error (line 12): Unexpected character $   
in "{{$required_resources}}" in    
modules/form_builder/customization/anatomy/header.html
```

Why would this occur? I thought raw/endraw is specifically there to allow embedding any content and not have it parsed by Jekyll?

I'm concerned this may cause issues.

Thanks!

Comment: Tried that code in a fresh install and works right, there may be something else in your config that is preventing the raw tag to work

Answer (score 1):

This *is* quite strange. The `{% raw %}` tag is supposed to prevent Liquid between the tags from being processed. It looks like Liquid might be reading the content between the tags here but not processing it.

It seems like a Liquid error. I'd encourage you to open an issue in the Liquid repo so the maintainers can figure out if this needs to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

You may try to narrow down the range of `{% raw %}` and `{% endraw %}`, like this.

```
<textarea class="codemirror" data-lang="html">
<html>
<head>
  <title>{{$form_name}}</title>
  {% raw %}{{$required_resources}}{% endraw %}
</head>
<body></textarea>
```

---

I come up with this idea while attempting to fix a Liquid syntax error for my post.

```
{% raw %}
{% quote author:"Free Software Foundation" title:"Introduction To the Command Line" %}
Hint: Do not try to learn all shortcuts at once!  The human brain isn't made for that kind of stuff, so you will forget almost all of them.  Rather, we advise you to learn the 4--5 shortcuts that you find most useful and use them regularly --- learning by doing.  Later, you can come back to this chapter to pick up more shortcuts.  You will soon find yourself whirling across the command line.
{% endquote %}
{% endraw %}
```

Error message:

```
  Liquid Exception: undefined method `getConverterImpl' for
#<Jekyll::Site:0x007fffc791f798> in /home/user/vincenttam.github.io
/_posts/2014-01-08-testing-online-code-syntax-highlighters-for-blogs-
5-embedding-makefiles-to-a-web-page.markdown
jekyll 3.3.1 | Error:  undefined method `getConverterImpl' for
#<Jekyll::Site:0x007fffc791f798>
```

If I surround both `{% quote %}` and `{% endquote %}` with `{% raw %}` and `{% endraw %}`, then it *won't* be parsed by Jekyll.

```
 {% raw %}
 {% quote author:"Free Software Foundation" title:"Introduction To the Command Line" %}
 {% endraw %}
 Hint: Do not try to learn all shortcuts at once!  The human brain isn't made for that kind of stuff, so you will forget almost all of them.  Rather, we advise you to learn the 4--5 shortcuts that you find most useful and use them regularly --- learning by doing.  Later, you can come back to this chapter to pick up more shortcuts.  You will soon find yourself whirling across the command line.
 {% raw %}
 {% endquote %}
 {% endraw %}
```